# How do I perform calculations with UIPickerView data?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I need to perform some calculations with the selection from a UIPickerView (Swift).  Is there no way to use an extension, like .floatValue to take the selected row's string, and convert it to a float? I've tried several different approaches, and all have failed.

My picker functions fine, and all delegates and datasources are assigned.

Here's what I have:

```
var spherePower : Float!
let overRefractionData = ["-1.00", "-0.75", "-0.50", "-0.25", "0", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75", "1.00"]
spherePower = // I need to pass the selected row's float value here
```

Answer (score 2):

Your picker's data source probably ought to be storing the values as floats in the first place, and then the delegate turns those floats into strings to display in the picker.

```
var overRefractionData = [-1.0, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return "\(overRefractionData[row])"
}
```

So when the user picks a value, you can just use the picked index to get the value from the data array:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var pickedValue = overRefractionData[row]
    // do something with the picked value...
}
```

Comment: While true for simple cases that it may be best to use float values for this, there could be a use case where the picker should display strings to give more information on what is being picked. For example, this numbers could have a label and would then be displayed as `["-1.00 units", "-0.75 units", ...]`. In this case they would want to keep the data source as strings, and on selection, extract the float value with NSScanner.

Comment: I don't agree. The data source should represent just that: data. If the purpose of the data is to form part of a mathematical expression, it should be stored in a way that reflects that purpose. You used the word "display", but display is very much the role of the view, not the model. In your example, the data should still be stored as numbers and the controller interpret this data for display in the view, appending any additional information to help the user understand what is being displayed ("units"). Scanning strings in labels to derive model data is not a good idea in principle.

Comment: I see what you mean. I suppose this would be the job of the view (or view model) to get the values from the data source, and display it in the way that is desired. Good points, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `pickerView(_ pickerView: didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` you can use the row value as the index for for your `overRefractionData`. Then cast the string to an NSString and use NSString's floatValue.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if (row < overRefractionData.count) {
        var selectedString = overRefractionData[row]
        var selectedFloatValue = (selectedString as NSString).floatValue
       // selectedFloatValue should now hold a float value
    }
}
```